# Jquery getting class list from parent of looped element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I created some checkboxes in HTML and now I would like to get the class list of the checkbox's parent every time it is checked.

For this, I looped through the checked elements and tried using `$(this).parent()` which indeed returned the parent, but if I add `.classList` to the end of it, undefined gets logged. I tried doing other stuff and `$(this).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );` works as planned.
It is also possible I may have structured my function incorrectly but I can't seem to find the mistake.
Could someone kindly point out why `$(this).parent().classList`
returns undefined?

Any help greatly appreciated.

```js
    jQuery(function($) {
        function getClassList (){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.single-checkbox').change(function() {
                    $('.single-checkbox').each(function() {
                        if( this.checked ){
                            console.log( $(this).parent() );
                            console.log( $(this).parent().classList );
                            $(this).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
    
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        getClassList();
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="input-wrapper post-id-145">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-116">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-176">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-151">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
```

Comment: `.attr('class')`

Comment: Thank you a lot, that works! Could you tell me why classList doesn't work?

Comment: You're welcome @Zae ..But what you need to know is: `.classList` is a pure javascript `$($(this).parent())[0].classList` then get classes by index `$($(this).parent())[0].classList[1]` and `$(this).parent()` is a jquery so you need to use  jquery `.attr('class')`..   Have a great day :) .. I guess your next task is to get the post id number .. because of that I recommend to use `data-post-id="number"` and then get the number using `.parent().attr('data-post-id')`

Comment: Thank you so much, cleared up a bunch!! :)

Answer (score 0):

There was so much to clean up in your code. Below is a working cleaned up version. Your IF was missing the end } and ..

These basically do the same
    jQuery(function($) { and $(document).ready(function(){

and you don't need to use this if you are checking for change even on page load

```
function getClassList (){
```

This is the updated code:

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.single-checkbox').change(function() {
                    $('.single-checkbox').each(function() {
                        if( this.checked ){
                            console.log( $(this).parent() );
                            console.log( $(this).parent().attr('class'));
                            $(this).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
                         }
                    });
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="input-wrapper post-id-145">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-116">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-176">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-151">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you do not need to check ischeckd or iterate over all checkbox..

```js
jQuery(function($) {
     $(".single-checkbox").change(function(){
       let classNames = $(this).parent().attr('class');
       //list of parrent classnames in array
       console.log(classNames.split(" "));
      })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="input-wrapper post-id-145">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-116">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-176">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
    
    <li class="input-wrapper post-id-151">
      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox">
    </li>
```